# Netlogo: runtime-error with list, item, and -1

Tags: list, runtime-error, netlogo

I have a rather specific error in netlogo that I've been staring at for a while now. Hope you guys have some insight.

The error is in a code which looks back in a list called 'strategy'. If the list is longer than investment-time variables 'REfocus' and 'PRICE' are set to a certain value. If the list is not longer than investment-time, the variables are not set (and thus remain 0).

The code consists out of a function strategy_actions and a reporter investment_time. Investment-time is approximately 3 years, but as ticks are in months, investment-time is rescaled to months. In strategy_actions, investment-time is scaled back to years, as each entry in the strategy list is also annual. (The scaling and rescaling seems arbitrary, but as investment-time is used a lot by other parts of the code, it made more sense to do it like this). The goal is to take the strategy from x time back (equal to investment-time).

The code (error follows underneath):

```
to strategy_actions
  set_ROI
  start_supply?
  if current_strategy != 0
  [
    let it (investment_time / 12)
    ifelse it >= length strategy
    [
      set REfocus 0
    ]
    [
      if item (it - 1) strategy  = 1
      [
        if supply? = true [set_PRICE (set_discrete_distribution 0.29 0.19 0.29 0.15 0.07 0 0) (set_discrete_distribution 0.14 0.12 0.25 0.25 0.25 0 0)]
        ifelse any? ids [set REfocus mean [mot_RE] of ids][set REfocus set_discrete_distribution 0.07 0.03 0.07 0.17 0.66 0 0]
      ]
      if item (it - 1) strategy = 2
      [
        if supply? = true [set_PRICE (set_discrete_distribution 0.27 0.21 0.32 0.11 0.09 0 0) (set_discrete_distribution 0.15 0.11 0.22 0.30 0.23 0 0)]
        ifelse any? prods [set REfocus mean [mot_RE] of prods][set REfocus set_discrete_distribution 0.12 0.03 0.10 0.18 0.57 0 0]
      ]
      if item (it - 1) strategy = 3
      [
        if supply? = true [set_PRICE (set_discrete_distribution 0.26 0.22 0.26 0.18 0.09 0 0) (set_discrete_distribution 0.07 0.08 0.19 0.30 0.35 0 0)]
        ifelse any? cons[set REfocus mean [mot_RE] of cons][set REfocus set_discrete_distribution 0.08 0.06 0.15 0.27 0.45 0 0]
      ]
    ]
  set RE_history fput REfocus RE_history
  ]
end

to-report investment_time
  report ((random-normal 3 1) * 12)  ;approximately 3 years investment time
end
```

somehow, i sometimes get this runtime error during my behaviorspace experiment:

`-1 isn't greater than or equal to zero.
error while observer running ITEM
  called by procedure STRATEGY_ACTIONS
  called by procedure SET_MEETING_ACTIONS
  called by procedure GO`

Does anyone know what causes this error?
You would help me out a lot!

Cheers,

Maria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that investment_time is occasionally coming in as zero, so you are asking for `item (0 - 1)` of the strategy list.  I did a bit of playing around with `item` and learned (to my surprise) that `item (0.0001 - 1) strategy` works just fine, yielding the 0th item in the list in spite of the argument being negative.  But `item (0 - 1) strategy` does give the error you cite.  Apparently an item number greater than -1 is interpreted as zero.  Indeed `item` seems to truncate any fractional argument rather than rounding it.  E.g., `item 0.9` is interpreted as `item 0`, as is `item -0.9`

That might be worth putting in the documentation.

HTH,
Charles

Comment: The `item` primitive uses Java casting, which truncates in the direction of 0,  to convert the floating point value to `int`. The relevant line in the NetLogo source code is [here](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/038379612cbf93346433b54291d5c63602a98e4c/netlogo-gui/src/main/prim/etc/_item.java#L24). As to whether it should be documented, I'm not sure it's worth burdening the dictionary entry for `item` with these considerations, but it probably should still be explained somewhere. You could open an issue: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/new

Comment: Thanks for your help. For some reason I forgot to round off the investment_time, so now the code is: `item (round it - 1) strategy`

My error remains. Any ideas on how to solve the error?

Perhaps I should decrease the standard deviation for investment_time, so that it is not 3 years with a standard deviation of 1, but 3 with a std of 0.5 for example. I will try this.

Comment: So I've changed the investment-time to a mean of 5 with a std of 1, and the error is a lot less frequent now. So item turns all the 0.9999's into 0's, is what you're saying right? So, using round before using item is a smart thing to do then. To make sure that all 0.555 becomes 1 first. Thank you for your assistance. And yeah, the thing with 0 - 1 and 0.0001 - 1 is strange indeed. Hope that if anyone else has an issue like this, they find some help in your comment.

Comment: If you are using the normal distribution, for instance, you still will get occasional values of investment_time of zero or below.  Perhaps you should check the value of investment_time and set non-positive values to some small positive value.  It won't be a nice normal distribution, but it may be fine for your purposes.